# debian apt-get permission denied

Tags: linux, debian, ovh

with a debian linux host (OVH pro)
when I run `apt-get install supervisor` I get

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13 Permission denied)
     E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

and also when I run su  it asks a password that doesn't seem to be the same as my ftp and I get (authentication failed) how can I solve that ? please

Answer (score 3):

You need to run `apt-get` with superuser permissions; either as root or with sudo. Try `sudo su -` to change to the root user. This requires your password. If you use `su -` it expects the root user's password.
Alternatively, you can use `sudo apt-get install supervisor` for the same result.

Comment: sudo: can't stat /etc/sudoers:no folder or file
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting

Comment: thanks Man , the problem when can I get the password of superuser , they only gave me the password of ftp

Comment: If it's not your server ("they only gave me the password of ftp") you should ask the owner (or whoever has superuser permissions) to install the supervisor package.

Comment: I think that OVH (pro) doesn't give the ability to access root

Comment: No way to install programs then, I'm afraid :(. At least not this way.